# Getting started with Step Functions and I can't get Choice to work correctly

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm doctoring up my first step function, and as a newb into this I am struggling to make this work right. The documentation on AWS is helpful but lacks examples of what I am trying understand. I found a couple similar issues on the site here, but they didn't really answer my question either.

I have a test Step Function that works really simply.  I have a small Lambda function that kicks out a single line JSON with a "Count" from a request in a DynamoDB:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """lambda_handler

    Keyword arguments:
    event -- dict -- A dict of parameters to be validated.
    context -- 

    Return:
    json object with the hubID from DynamoDB of the new hub. 

    Exceptions:
    None
    """
    # Prep the Boto3 resources needed
    dynamodb        = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table           = dynamodb.Table('TransitHubs')

    # By default we assume there are no new hubs
    newhub = { 'Count' : 0 }

    # Query the DynamoDB to see if the name exists or not:
    response = table.query(
        IndexName='Status-index',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('Status').eq("NEW"),
        Limit=1
    )

    if response['Count']:
        newhub['Count'] = response['Count']

    return json.dumps(newhub)
```

A normal output would be:

> {   "Count": 1 }

And then I create this Step Function:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Task",
  "States": {
        "Task": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:OMGSUPERSECRET:function:LaunchNode-get_new_hubs",
      "TimeoutSeconds": 60,
      "Next": "Choice"
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Count",
          "NumericEquals": 0,
          "Next": "Failed"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.Count",
          "NumericEquals": 1,
          "Next": "Succeed"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Succeed": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    },
    "Failed": {
      "Type": "Fail"
    }
  }
}
```

So I kick off the State Function and I get this output:

**TaskStateExited**

```
{
  "name": "Task",
  "output": {
    "Count": 1
  }
}
```

**ChoiceStateEntered**

```
{
  "name": "Choice",
  "input": {
    "Count": 1
  }
}
```

**ExecutionFailed**

```
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'Choice' (entered at the event id #7). Invalid path '$.Count': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."
}
```

So my question: I don't get why this is failing with that error message.  Shouldn't Choice just pick up that value from the JSON? Isn't the default "$" input the "input" path?

Comment: In the step functions console on your failed execution, when you click the `Task` Lambda, and click the 'Output' tab, that will show the actual output of the Lambda.  Does that show the structure you expect?

Comment: Thanks, that's partly what did lead me to figuring this out.  I documented the answer to my issue below.

Answer (score 5):

I have figured out what the issue is, and here it is:

In my Python code, I was attempting to json.dumps(newhub) for the response thinking that what I needed was a string output representing the json formatted response.  But it appears that is incorrect.  When I alter the code to be simply "return newhub" and return the DICT, the step-functions process accepts that correctly.  I'm assuming it parses the DICT to JSON for me?  But the output difference is clearly obvious:

**old Task output from above returning json.dumps(newhub):**

```
{
  "name": "Task",
  "output": {
    "Count": 1
  }
}
```

**new Task output from above returning newhub:**

```
{
  "Count": 1
}
```

And the Choice now correctly matches the Count variable in my output.

Comment: Thank you, was doing exactly that :D

Answer (score 3):

In case this is helpful for someone else. I also experienced the kind of error you did ( you had the below... just copy-pasting yours... )

```
{
"error": "States.Runtime",
"cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'Choice' (entered at the event id #7). Invalid path '$.Count': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."
}
```

But my problem turned out when I was missing the `"Count"` key all together.

But I did not want verbose payloads.

But per reading [these docs](https://states-language.net/spec.html#choice-state) I discovered I can also do...

```
"Choice": {
"Type": "Choice",
"Choices": [
  {
    "And": [
      {
          "Variable": "$.Count",
          "IsPresent": true
          },
      {
          "Variable": "$.Count",
          "NumericEquals": 0,
          }
      ],
    "Next": "Failed"
    },
  {
    "And": [
      {
          "Variable": "$.Count",
          "IsPresent": true
          },
      {

          "Variable": "$.Count",
          "NumericEquals": 1,
          }
      ],
    "Next": "Succeed"
    }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

even I was facing the same issue. Give the ResultPath as InputPath and give the choice value as .value name

```
{
  "Comment": "Step function to execute lengthy synchronous requests",
  "StartAt": "StartProcessing",
  "States": {
    "StartProcessing": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:703569030910:function:shravanthDemo-shravanthGetItems-GHF7ZA1p6auQ",
      "InputPath": "$.lambda",
      "ResultPath": "$.lambda",
      "Next": "VerifyProcessor"
    },
    "VerifyProcessor": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.lambda.cursor",
          "IsNull": false,
          "Next": "StartProcessing"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.lambda.cursor",
          "IsNull": true,
          "Next": "EndOfUpdate"
        }
      ]
    },
    "EndOfUpdate": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "ProcessingComplete",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```